# Scroll Parent ListView when nested ListView.builder is updated

Tags: flutter, listview

I have a ListView with, say, PostItems being generated with ListView.builder.

Each PostItem MAY have comments on it. So each PostItem has a nested ListView.builder to show comments for that PostItem.

User can add a Comment to the nested ListView. However, UX would like to scroll to that newly added Comment in the nested ListView. Nested Listview shrinkwrap is true, with NeverScrollable Physics. When nested Comment listview expandeds with new Comment, it's off screen and I want to scroll down to it.

ListView.builder -> PostItem -> Nested ListView.builder

However, my assumption is that I need to make the parent ListView scroll down but how do I know where to scroll to when it's the Nested listview that has grown in height.

I can't share code due to the project but any theological thoughts or ideas would be a great help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can see that, based on your description, we can access the index of that particular `ListView`. Thus, I would suggest you to use this package to achieve what you want:

[scroll_to_index](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Thank you for your input. So yes I do have the index of the parent listview. However, each element in the parent listview, potentially has it's OWN listview that could be a dynamic size. The ask is for the parent listview to scroll to the index, but the bottom of it, to the extent of that particular index's child listview height. Hope that clears it up? Thank you again!